# Magento Product Add to Cart after Login for Selected Category

Tags: cart, category

In Magento, is it possible to add the product to cart after login for the selected category.

The selected category products, which can be view for all user while add this product to cart it should check whether the user is login, if the user is login product should be added to cart else it should go to my account page after user login that product should added to cart and the user also redirect to the cart page.

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with an extension that uses an observer. You can observer the `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` event in this case.

```
<config>
    [...]
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_module_add_product>
                        <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                        <method>checkLogin</method>
                    </namespace_module_add_product>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    [...]
</config>
```

and your observer would look something like this. Before the product is added to cart the function checks if the current customer is logged in. If not it redirects to the login page.

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
   public function checkLogin($observer)
   {
      if (!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())
      {
         Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
         exit;
      }
   }
}
```

**[EDIT]** - another, little les techincal, option.

An other option would be to hide the add to cart button whenever a customer is not logged in yet. In the file `app/design/frontend/[template]/[package]/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml` you can wrap the add to cart in an if statement. Your file would look something like this.

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$requirelogincategory = [ID of the category that requires login];
$buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart');

if(Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() || Mage::registry('current_category')!=$requirelogincategory): 
    if($_product->isSaleable()): 
?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php 
    endif;
else:
?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Please <a href="%s">login</a> to buy this product', Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));?></p>
<?php
endif; 
?>
```

Comment: After changing 'Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));' to 'echo Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
   exit();' it redirect, but after login it not goes to cart page, and i want to set it for selected category only

Comment: I've updated my answer with another option that might be more suited to what you require

Comment: sander, for selected categories this works well,now my problem is after the user login it not goes to cart page. eg. if the user not login and click addtocart it goes to customer account page, after login it should redirect to cart page with adding that product

Comment: That's strange. it should redirect to the last page. If not you might have to edit the customer controller that handles the login request

Comment: i have tried but the product is not added to the cart, just it redirect to cart page

Comment: Is this when you try the second solution I've suggested instead of the first?

Comment: no, your second solution do the same as first solution with filtered the selected category for redirected to login page,